# Answers of questionable legality?

Tags: discussion, answers, flagging

One of the answers to my 70-576 question seems to be linking to an illegal download of a course in video form:

[70-576 Study Material](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11421/70-576-study-material/11431#11431)

Is this flagworthy, or not offensive enough to warrant action?

Edit: I should note that it's the second comment that's questionable.

Comment: Come on, this should have been a no-brainer. :)

Comment: @ScarePoint: Maybe. The problem is that it actually answered the question quite usefully; admittedly only for those of loose morals... Similarly @moontear mentions a resource of similar legality (with more subtlety) in the comments with regards to brain-dumps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I flagged that one as offensive. Not the kind of content we want on our site.

Comment: I thought similar, especially given the NSFW adverts on that site.